# Python underflow should be less precise

Tags: python, underflow

I tried this very simple code to see the python underflow in action by calculating the absolute and relative error between 2 functions:

```
from pylab import *

n = 2000
x = logspace(-17,-16,n)

y1 = 1/(1+x) - 1/(1-x)
y2 = (-2 *x)/((1+x)*(1-x))

ea = abs(y1 - y2)

er = ea/abs(y2)

loglog(x[ea>0], er[ea>0])
```

Normally the underflow should appear for x <= 2^-53 but here he appears for x <= 2^-54 = 5.55e-17. cf:

[curve of the evolution of the relative error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXd3b.png)

I can't figure out why, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should add your import lines, and, if needed, mention which projects you are using so that anyone can re-run your code  - a minimal reproducible example is key for answering some questions.  Without knowing which project suplies `logspace' and `loglog` one can't even start investigating.  (putting the project use in the tafs also help)

Comment: I've edited my post so that everyone can see the includes. Thanks for the advice. Also, I'm running my code on spyder.